# Layer adding/removing using PyQGIS?

Tags: layers, pyqgis-3

I'm working on a plugin which fetch data from Vector Layers and I'm trying to update the informations whenever a fitting layer is added or removed.

At first, I tried with `QgsProject.layersAdded` and `QgsProject.layersRemoved` but it did nothing so I searched a little and found people mentioning `layerTreeRoot.addedChildren` and `layerTreeRoot.removedChildren`. Now my slots are activated however they seem to run before the action is actually performed.

Is this normal and are there other signals which could fit my needs?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Thanks.